# best way to iterate over elements of web page in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension and trying to iterate over the elements of a web page which has multiple instances of the format shown below:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="loud" style="text-decoration: none;">...</span>
  <div class="leave-gap">...</div>
  <p>"Some text"</p>
  <span id="id_12345" class="none">...</span>
  <div class="block-footer">...</div>
  <div class="leave-gap">...</div>
</div>
```

Basically under certain conditions I am going to hide between the first `leave-gap` class and the `block-footer` class.

I propose to find the `loud` classes as follows:

```
$('.wrapper .loud').each(function() 
{
  var $a = $(this);
  ...
```

Assuming that I use syntax of the form `$a.next()` to find each subsequent element, how would I determine the class of the element?

Is there a quicker way of doing this than my proposed solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean like $a.next('.leave-gap') ?

Comment: you can check if a class exists by $(element).hasClass('leave-gap')

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I need to have a play with this. As you can probably tell from the question I am fairly new to Javascript and this is a "lunch time" project. You have all been very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$(element).children().each(loopfunction)` to do the trick.

Assuming you want to hide all content between the two specific element.

check the test case:

```js
$('.wrapper').each(function() {
    var foundgap = false
    $(this).children().each(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('leave-gap')) {
            foundgap = true; // mark the beginning of block
            return;
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('block-footer')) {
            return false; // meet the end, break 'each' loop
        } else if (foundgap) {
            $(this).hide(); // I'm inside the block. do whatever you need
        }
    })
});
```

```css
*:not(body):not(html) {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="loud" style="text-decoration: none;">loud1</span>
  <div class="leave-gap">leave-gap</div>
  <p>"Some text"</p>
  <span id="id_12345" class="none">id</span>
  <div class="block-footer">fotter</div>
  <div class="leave-gap">leave-gap</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="loud" style="text-decoration: none;">loud2</span>
  <div class="leave-gap">leave-gap</div>
  <p>"Some text"</p>
  <span id="id_12345" class="none">id</span>
  <div class="block-footer">fotter</div>
  <div class="leave-gap">leave-gap</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you found the element in your way, to find the class of the element,

`$(element).attr("class")`

or you can verify the class is the one you want,

`$(element).hasClass("className")`

Answer (score 1):

One possibility in modern Javascript.

```js
var firstLeaveGaps = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper .leave-gap:first-of-type');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(firstLeaveGaps, function (leaveGap) {
    var next = leaveGap.nextElementSibling;

    while (next) {
        if (next.classList.contains('block-footer')) {
            break;
        }
        
        next.style.display = 'none';
        next = next.nextElementSibling;
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="loud" style="text-decoration: none;">loud</span>
  <div class="leave-gap">leave-gap</div>
  <p>"Some text"</p>
  <span id="id_12345" class="none">id</span>
  <div class="block-footer">block-footer</div>
  <div class="leave-gap">leave-gap</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="loud" style="text-decoration: none;">loud</span>
  <div class="leave-gap">leave-gap</div>
  <p>"Some text"</p>
  <span id="id_54321" class="none">id</span>
  <div class="block-footer">block-footer<div>
  <div class="leave-gap">leave-gap</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Whie use this verbose vanilla code if he can do it in 2 lines with jQuery ?

Comment: `Is there a quicker way of doing this than my proposed solution?` and where is this 2 lines of jQuery that is quicker?

Comment: And the question title `best way to iterate over elements of web page in JavaScript/jQuery` and opening sentence of the question `I am developing a Chrome extension` - modern

Answer (score 0):

You can hide `div` tag with `class name` also.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//may be you can put the below in a function and call it when you condition meet.
    $('.leave-gap').hide();
    $('.block-footer').hide();
});
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sO10yjhLmowXqgzClIC4?p=preview)

[Other link: find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/), [class-selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Comment: Thanks Mike. How would I hide the <p>"Some text"</p>  part using this technique?

Comment: $('p').hide() - I said I was new to this stuff!